# Collaborative software recommendation for a 4 year research project with several partners and < 10 researchers

Tags: projects, lab-management

I will be a project manager of research project with 3 university partners, 3 Postdocs and 5 PhD students for 4 years.

Currently we use software tools for single researchers in my group like mendeley, github, moinmoinwiki (intranet on all workgroup PC's).

For this new project this will not cover all demands:

- sharing of data files, best case also everyone can comment data, everyone should be able to upload/download data (not more than 10 GB needed as mainly PDF or rawd data is shared) to a secured space over internet (industry research and patent relevant data), so no intranet possible
- should be future proof (data security), no software without updates for the next 4-5 years which rules out many open source wiki software to my knowledge
- data security (I know *slack* for instance, but can I really trust this software, it not being hacked or is it not better to use your own server (or university space) and some wiki with only password access.
- no steep learning curve, should motivate to use it, no special syntax to learn, rather WYSIWYG like moinmoinwiki/Word editor.
- no high price
- file sharing, www blog entries, user access/login area technically necessary

What is currently common for funded research projects. Unfortunately this long [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_collaborative_software) is not showing what is popular for research/academia and I don't think a general industry collaborative software matches the same needs as described above.

What would you recommend or is there a singe solution? Tiki Wiki looks interesting but complex, maybe wordpress and old school FTP is better?!